# Print for each batch in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

The spark streaming application is not printing statements. Here I am trying to print some statement, just after transforming the DataFrame, but it is only getting printed for the first batch only. I expected it to be printed for every batch execution. My code is below:

```
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

  var df = dataFrame.select(colNames(i)).as[Array[Byte]].
    map(x => {
      // some processing
    }).toDF()

  df.createOrReplaceTempView("newName")
  log.info("Processing Time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))
```

But this log is printed only for the 1st time when the code is loaded.

Because this is apache.spark.sql.DataFrame object, there is no forEachRdd method. I also tried

```
df.foreachPartition(x => log.info("Processing Time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)))
```

But I get below error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

Is there anyway I can print this log for each batch?

Comment: Can you show full code, at least where you define your stream.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch

Comment: Can you post full code ??

Comment: What about `foreach` operator?

Comment: Foreach will print for each row in DataFrame. I just want it to get printed once for each DataFrame.